# I over seasoned BBQ chicken with too much salt how do I fix it

Tags: chicken

I BBQ a case of chicken for a family reunion it is extremely salty how do I fix it

Comment: Adding the recipe and technique you used will help get better answers.  That said, usually the best advice for over-salting is to dilute the recipe somehow (the specifics depend on where and how the over-salting happened)

Comment: Sorry...voted to close, but didn't realize this is an old question, however, my linked question does predate it

Comment: @moscafj that's OK - it just means that we missed the duplicate when the question was first asked. There is no rule that only recent question should be closed as duplicates, quite the opposite - we correct our oversights when we come across them, as part of good housekeeping.

Answer (score 0):

Salt will stay on or close to the skin of the chicken, so if you've over-salted the skin the simplest way to fix it is to remove the skin and not serve it.

Answer (score 0):

Rinse chicken in water then add it back to the grill with low fire...brush ckn with honey.  The honey will balance the salt.  Just keep an eye on it as the honey can burn fairly quickly.  Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

please sqeeuze some lemon juice and let the chicken absorb the the juice for a while(2 mins)

Comment: And that would acchieve what exactly? Why? This needs more details.

Comment: because lemon juice will help to reduce salt level in your dish specially when you are dealing with spicy BBQ recipes and it will taste good ... I have tried this tip on my BBQ potatoes and works for me

Comment: Now that should best be an [edit] to your post!